# cakephp: get values from a "cat" table in the "users_controller.php" file?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

i have table "User" and a Controller "users_controller.php"
and i have another table called "cateogry", need to retrieve values from this table in the 
"listall" action(**site.com/users/listall**).

how can i get values from another table.

Answer (score 1):

To fill a select element containing categories, supposing you have a User belongsTo Category relationship :

- in the controller, get the categories ready to be used in a select element

```
$categories = $this->User->Category->find('list');
$this->set(compact('categories'));
```

- in the view add your select element :

```
echo $form->input('User.category_id');
```

Cake will automatically use the values contained in the `$categories` variable for the `category_id` select thanks to the Inflector. If for some reason your values are in a different variable, use

```
echo $form->input('User.category_id', array('options' => $values_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a hasMany relation between your User and Category models ?

Then it's deadly easy.

```
$this->User->find('first')->Category->find('all');
```

Will retrieve every category associated with the user.

Some resources that might be helpful to you :

- [Relations Types](http://book.cakephp.org/view/79/Relationship-Types)
- [Retrieving Data](http://book.cakephp.org/view/73/Retrieving-Your-Data)

Comment: i need to fill some values from "cat" table to a "select" element in the registration. suppose for the signup page list all the countries form the country table

Comment: `->find('first')->Category` seems odd, don't you just mean `User->Category` ?

Answer (score 0):

/models/user.php:

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
var $hasMany = array('Category');
```

/controllers/users_controller.php:

```
function listall()
{
    $users = $this->User->find('all', array('contain' => array('Category')));
    $this->set('users', $users);
}
```

/views/users/listall.ctp:

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($user['User']['username']);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($user['User']['Category'] as $category)
    {
        echo '<li>';
        echo htmlspecialchars($category['description']);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

use the debug function to reveal the $users array:

```
debug($users);
```

Check out the documentation on containable behaviour:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable